# Error Event Dojo Change event and query feature layer

Tags: dojo, arcgis-js-api

> From a select list and a feature layer, I´m trying to make a query feature layer but I don´t know what´s going on

```
<select name="select1" id="select">
            <option value="Artesania">Artesania</option>
            <option value="Banco" selected="selected">Banco</option>
            <option value="Bar">Bar</option>
            <option value="Bodega">Bodega</option>
            <option value="Boutique">Boutique</option>
            <option value="Discoteca">Discoteca</option>
/select>
```

> ---

```
   var mapMain;
    require([
            "esri/map",
            "dojo/ready",
            "dojo/parser",
            "dojo/on",
            "dojo/dom",

            "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
            "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
            "esri/dijit/HomeButton",
            "esri/dijit/Scalebar",
            "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
            "esri/tasks/QueryTask",
            "esri/tasks/query",
            "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
            "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
            "esri/Color",
            "dijit/form/Select"],
        function (Map,
                  ready,
                  parser,
                  on,
                  dom,
                  BorderContainer,
                  ContentPane,
                  HomeButton,
                  Scalebar,
                  FeatureLayer,
                  QueryTask,
                  Query,
                  SimpleMarkerSymbol,
                  SimpleLineSymbol,
                  Color
                  ) {


            ready(function () {

                 parser.parse();


            // Create the map
                mapMain = new Map("cpCenter", {
                    basemap: "topo",
                    center: [-5.61094, 36.016],
                    zoom: 15
                });//map

                var home = new HomeButton({
                map: mapMain
                }, "HomeButton");
                home.startup();//homebutton

                var scalebar = new Scalebar({
                map: mapMain,
                scalebarUnit: "dual"
                });//scalebar
```

> I suspect my problem is the event change

```
                on(select, "change", function(evt){                

                    var SeleccLocal = dom.byId("select").value;

                  alert("Valor del select es: " + SeleccLocal);
```

> Define a query, after that I will create a Feature Layer

```
                    var query = new Query();
                    query.where = "Tienda = " + SeleccLocal;
                    query.returnGeometry = true;
                    console.log(query)   

>  Create a new symbol

                    var marker = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_SQUARE, 10,
                    new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
                    new Color([255,0,0]), 1),
                    new Color([0,255,0,0.25]));
```

> Create a FeatureLayer with a query selection

```
                    var localOSM = new FeatureLayer(localesOSM);
                    localOSM.selectFeatures(query,FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW);
                    //localOSM.setDefinitionExpression("Tienda = Discoteca");
```

> Add the symbol into feature layer

```
                   localOSM.setSelectionSymbol(marker);
```

> Add Feature Layer

```
                   mapMain.addLayer(localOSM);

                });//on select      

            });//ready
    });//requiere
```

> > And I always obtain the same error
> >         dojo.io.script error Error: Failed to execute query.
> >             at Object.h.load (init.js:885)
> >             at init.js:191
> >             at c (init.js:76)
> >             at d (init.js:76)
> >             at b.Deferred.resolve.callback (init.js:77)
> >             at c (init.js:76)
> >             at d (init.js:76)
> >             at b.Deferred.resolve.callback (init.js:77)
> >             at init.js:1507
> >             at k (init.js:199)

Comment: What is your question? If it works then it makes sense; otherwise it doesn't

Comment: is there many featureLayers ?? wand what's the value of `locales` variable url ?

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve? better to create running sample and pointOut what exectly is not working...

Comment: I´ve had some changes but it doesn´t work, that´s the complete js code and the error. Any ideas?.

Comment: It´s only one feature layer whom I want to do the query

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/btsfufms/

Comment: you missed to complete the require for the dijit/form/select. At the end of the function, under the "Color" there must be an additional entry like "Select"